# Java Hashtable linked list

Tags: java, types, linked-list, hashtable

Hi I have the following code for some reason it is throwing a type error: `Expected String, Actual Object`. Its a hashtable with `string` keys and `linkedlist<string>` values.

When iterating through these `linkedlist` I'm unable to set their values to a `string` variable. I've used to the `getClass()` method to ensure it is returning a `string` class which it is. I'm very confused and any help would be appreciated.

```
Enumeration t = Scope.keys();
String temp_string;
String temp_string2;
LinkedList temp_linkedlist;
while (t.hasMoreElements())
{
    temp_string = (String)t.nextElement();
    temp_linkedlist = (LinkedList)Scope.get(temp_string);
    for(int num=0; num<temp_linkedlist.size(); num++)
    {
        //Prints out string from linked list  
        System.out.println(temp_linkedlist.get(num).getClass());
        //throws error 
        temp_string2 = temp_linkedlist.get(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post full statck trace of the error and specify the line in your code in which you have this error?

Comment: Besides the missing cast, for performance reasons You should not call `size()` and `get(num)` on a linked list. It is better to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

When not using generics, all elements in a list are considered `Object`'s to the compiler.

To make your code work, whilst keeping generics out of the equation, try the following:

```
temp_string2 = (String)temp_linkedlist.get(num);
```

The reason getClass() gives you a String is because it is evaluated at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would i do it with generics?